# How to delete email messages on a sendmail server?

Tags: email, sendmail

I have been searching for an answer to this question for the last 2 hours. I have a sendmail server with one mailbox that has 13,000+ email messages in it. Today the user opened Outlook and it began to download all of these messages even though most were already downloaded by Outlook previously -- which is duplicating all 13,000. Thankfully she closed Outlook at about the 1,000 downloaded mark. The user has the "Delete from server after 20 days" set in Outlook.

I need to delete via the command line all messages between February 11 and February 29th in this users mailbox. I know how to delete messages from the queue, but not from the mailbox, because I'm really not sure where the email message files reside.

I would really appreciate any help or pointing me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of mailserver? Is this exchange?

Comment: CentOS server running "sendmail".

Comment: Ok, good! :P, I have no experience using the default MTA with centos, but I use a Postfix/courier setup. in each user's maildir (in this case ~/.maildir) ther is a .Sent folder which contains the Sent messages, along with cur,tmp,new folders and sub-folders which store all the emails. Old, read emails are stored in the cur folders. I hope this leads you to the right path, but for all I know the maildir structure of sendmail might not be close :(

Answer (score 0):

The usual configuration is that sendmail puts mail to a user in /var/spool/mail/[username].  That file is just all the messages for the user concatenated together.  (Each message starts with a line that starts "From ".)

I think you can tell for sure by looking at /etc/sendmail.cf.  Look for a line starting "Mlocal".  That describes how local e-mail is to be delivered.  The "P=" part of the line tells what program does the work.  I think CentOS currently specifies /usr/bin/procmail, and if the user does not have a ~/.procmail file, it does what I described above.

You can simply move the /var/spool/mail file to another directory in the / partition -- that's safe because mv within a filesystem is atomic at the kernel level.  Then you can edit the file how ever you want.  It's a little touchier putting the edited file back, because you might do it at the same moment sendmail is delivering another message.  The safest way is to stop sendmail, then concatenate the messages you want to retain onto /var/spool/mail/[user], or if it doesn't exist, just move it back.  Then restart sendmail.